# How can I link libc++ on macOS?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++, libc++

I'm trying to learn C++ on macOS 11.2 (x86-64), and I'm having trouble compiling and linking my code. My simple program is listed below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class I>
void pancake_sort(I first, I last)
{
    for (; first != last; first++){
        std::reverse(std::min_element(first, last), last);
        std::reverse(first, last);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto a = std::vector<int64_t>(argc - 1);
    std::transform(&argv[1], &argv[1] + (argc - 1), a.begin(), atoll);
    pancake_sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to compile with `clang -std=c++11 <filename>`, but I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >::__vallocate(unsigned long) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "std::length_error::~length_error()", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "typeinfo for std::length_error", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "vtable for std::length_error", referenced from:
      std::length_error::length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::_DeallocateCaller::__do_call(void*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__libcpp_allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >::vector(unsigned long) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      std::__1::__vector_base<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >::__vector_base() in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >::__construct_at_end(unsigned long) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      std::__1::vector<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >::max_size() const in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      std::__1::__throw_length_error(char const*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      std::__1::__vector_base<long long, std::__1::allocator<long long> >::__destruct_at_end(long long*) in pancake_sort-cdbf1e.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried adding the flag `-stdlib=libstdc++`, but it seems like `libstdc++` is no longer included with macOS. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: You need to use `clang++` instead of `clang` for compilation.

Comment: While there is nothing wrong compiling from CLI, I highly recommend using Xcode to develop with C++ on macOS. Among plenty of advantages like debugging and profiling, an IDE will not make basic errors like calling `clang` instead of `clang++`.

Comment: @prapin I disagree, and many people seem to agree with me: Xcode isn't very well liked in the C++ community, most people use other IDEs/editors for C++ on macOS. It works just fine. You don't even need to install Xcode, all you need is the command line tools.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am not telling that other IDE for C++ are bad. But I can assure, from my experience of 8 years of C++ development on Xcode, that Xcode is also a great tool for C++ development, although it highlights only Swift. Anyway, I am pretty certain that working with an IDE (whichever you prefer) is more productive than without an IDE at all.

Comment: OP here. I was getting set up with VSCode, which seems pretty nice. Thank you again, @KonradRudolph for pointing out my mistake. I facepalmed when I realized what it was.

Comment: @prapin That highly depends on what you call an IDE: if you include Vim and Emacs then sure. Either way, none of this will prevent you from having to work with the command line at least occasionally, since most build systems *don’t* use Xcode, so if you ever need to compile other projects you’ll have to do so from the command line. When working with C++, knowing the command line compilation tools is simply indispensable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Konrad Rudolph, the solution is to use `clang++` instead of `clang` to compile C++ code.